# Append tag value and attributes to same tag in dexml model

Tags: python, xml

Using [dexml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dexml/) python  I was wondering how could I append tag value as well as attributes to the same tag.

For example:

```
<Person name="Any name">Another Value Here</Person>
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like this:

```
>>>import dexml
>>> from dexml import fields
>>> class Person(dexml.Model):
    ...   name = fields.String(attrname="name")
```

Comment: I need to add another value between the opening and closing tags as I mentioned in "Value" part

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any documentation on that but it seems that the text node is accessible through the tagname '.':

```
import dexml
from dexml import fields

class Person(dexml.Model):
    name = fields.String()
    text = fields.String(tagname='.')
```